# Web app security architecture

Tags: java, spring, rest, security, tomcat

I have a Java Spring driven REST API server connecting with PostgreSQL database and a Spring Web Server in Java that is serving content from the REST API to the client using JavaScript (now browsers, but in the future also mobile apps).

I've read a number of articles and topics how one can secure a REST API, but I haven't been able to make a final decision yet. I don't want to have Basic Authorization, because it doesn't make sense as I would need to store credentials in JavaScript that can be easily accessed and read by anyone entering the webpage and developer console. I'd like not to show any credentials to the end user so I can't keep them on the client's side.

I've read a lot about JWT and almost decided to implement it, but I've heard it has some drawbacks and haven't been so sure since then if it's the option I would like to choose. I know there is also oAuth 1.0 or oAuth 2.0 but I don't know if I want to have something this complicated. I would also like to store hashed user credentials in my own database in order not to be depended to any other credential providers like social media or Google.

Now I'm making another layer on my web server as a proxy hoping that it will allow me to authenticate user on this proxy level using Spring Security and having some kind or cookies or something to authenticate, but I'm not so sure if its doable this way and it increases the respond time, adds complexity and needs me to write controller methods for these endpoints. My architecture now is of the following:

*Client (browser) -> Webserver -> REST API server -> db*

I've also denied all external connections and allowed only localhost access to REST API on tomcat level so that I'd have to implement the security level only on the web server allowing free information transit between the webserver and REST API as it is not reachable anyway.

Web server and REST API are on the same server running as Tomcat instances.

I'm also not so sure if this kind of architecture will allow me to authenticate mobile app clients through the web server.

I would be very grateful for any piece of advice you would have for me in this matter. I'm not so experienced in security, so I'm a bit lost what I should do. Does this kind of architecture any sense or should I simply ask REST API directly from any type of clients, be it a webpage or a mobile app from different IPs and secure Rest API only? And if I want to secure some subpages of my webpage or parts of mobile app should that be an completely other layer?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have a look: https://medium.com/vandium-software/5-easy-steps-to-understanding-json-web-tokens-jwt-1164c0adfcec
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2

Comment: What drawbacks of JWT are you referring to?

Comment: @braunpet I've read that JWT tokens cannot be revoked and changing the user's permission cannot take place instantly, because it takes time to refresh tokens which grant/deny access to some features according to the new user authentication role (for instance if I grant admin access to a user it takes time before the token must expire before the user can receive a new one with access to admin panel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already gone through OAuth, JWT tokens etc. If you don't want to use them,then you can create your `own token based authentication system`.(say '`TokenHandler`').

**How this TokenHandler will work ?**

TokenHandler will be like a gateway server i.e your every REST API request will route through this server application. So you will address your confusion of mobile and web application call with a `authToken in header`. Main responsibility of this server applciation is to accept the token and validate against the database where all token details are maintain. This DB will have information regarding timestamp when token was last used to validate, to decide your validation rule .

**How Token will get generated ?**
Token can be any random 64 digit alphanumeric string and will be generated and updated in DB during every single login activity. Login webservice returns this token in response body.

**What can be rules for validation ?** 
It can be depending on your business logic. I preferred to keep active session window of 15 mins. Means if you access the webservice you will get active window of 15 more minutes. If you didn't access any service for 15 consecutive minutes then from 16th Minute you will need to login again to access further calls. This part can change according to requirements.

**How client side will handle this ?**
Client side will store this token and pass this token with every request call. Token Handler will validate and redirects it's request to the application server . So your one token handler can be used to server authentication of multiple applcation servers. This you can achieve by application end point identifer.

I will like to discuss further if you have any questions or suggestions .

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for the idea. Could you please tell me how this differs from JWT? Sounds very similar to me. Would it allow me also to grant my users different authorization roles: for instance ordinary user and admin with access to the restricted parts of my website?

Comment: Yes , it is moreover similar to JWT with only difference you are handling complete validation logic and yes your tokens can be used to identify the user and if token is valid then webservice can return the access information as well in same webservice.

Answer (score 1):

Use API Gateway Architecture Pattern for your use case -
 http://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html .

The API Gateway (The *webserver* in your question) can act as single entry point for all desktop/mobile clients. You can use either session cookies or jwts to authenticate clients at gateway.

With respect to authentication between gateway and micro services, and between micro services, i would suggest mutual ssl - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/326574/An-Introduction-to-Mutual-SSL-Authentication. If you are using spring boot, this might help - http://www.opencodez.com/java/implement-2-way-authentication-using-ssl.htm

The problem with IP white-listing approach is that - it's not well suitable for cloud architecture as the IPs might change with every server reboot. Even if you are using dedicated IPs, you should be careful to secure the communication with SSL/TLS, else attackers can easily sniff your traffic.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your response. Could you please tell me if I should validate a request only at Gateway? If I understood correctly, I don't have to validate requests to REST API server as they had been already validated at a Gateway right? I mean, for instance if a request body contains valid JSON. Is it a good practice not to validate input at REST API server or should I do it in both places just in case?

Comment: You can validate "session" or "tokens" only at gateway. With respect to request validations , they should happen everywhere. For example, you have a text field which should not be more than 100 characters - such validation should happen way until you store in your database (not just at one level).

Comment: Thank you. Correct me please if I'm wrong: does it mean that I have to validate input at client level, later at gateway and api layer? Validation at client level will be of course different, but I would end up with the same validation code at gateway and api then, does this code duplication is desirable in such a configuration?

Comment: You can skip the request validation at gateway layer but it is must at service layer. The gateway no need to validate the request body (it can be like a reverse proxy). Typically, following can be the duties of gateway:
1. User Authentication
2. Some level of Authorization (based on url path)
3. Security checks like Cross Site Request Forgery
4. Unifying response data from multiple services (if needed).
It's not required to mimic all the api calls at various services at gateway. There can be a generic controller which can pass through the request payload.